# How to deploy a ML model for entity extraction (with SVM or Perceptron)

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, svm, named-entity-recognition, perceptron

I am trying to extract soft skills from vacancies and I am currently struggling with applying a ML model (SVM or Perceptron) to my dataset. First I made a custom spaCy NER that eventually resulted in a dataset for the model to train upon. This dataset looks like this:

```
        words   POS        labels
37         We  PRON             O
38        are   AUX             O
39     always   ADV             O
40         on   ADP             O
41        the   DET             O
42    lookout  NOUN             O
43        for   ADP             O
44  motivated   ADJ  I-SOFT_SKILL
45       life  NOUN             O
46    science  NOUN             O
```

I want to extract the skills in different vacancies. And I created a perceptron that seems to be working.

```
print('the shape is: ',X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
per = Perceptron(verbose=10, n_jobs=-1, max_iter=10)
per.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes)
```

**Output**

```
the shape is:  (51759, 6155) (51759,)

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
-- Epoch 1-- Epoch 1

Norm: 17.15, NNZs: 95, Bias: -3.000000, T: 51759, Avg. loss: 0.009795
Total training time: 0.55 seconds.
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 37.97, NNZs: 378, Bias: -3.000000, T: 51759, Avg. loss: 0.018296
Total training time: 0.57 seconds.
Norm: 42.68, NNZs: 457, Bias: 3.000000, T: 51759, Avg. loss: 0.025696
Total training time: 0.50 seconds.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:    1.1s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:    1.1s finished
Perceptron(max_iter=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)
```

Now, when I try to apply the model to completely unseen data, I get a ValueError:

```
ValueError: X has 6747 features, but Perceptron is expecting 6155 features as input.
```

so does the amount of features in the unseen vacancies need to be exactly the same as in the training model? Or is there another, better way to do this?

If additional information is needed I can provide that! Would be thankful if somebody knew the problem!

Comment: How is your X train looks like? Why you have 6155 features? X must have same structure of X_train. If you trained the model with 10 columns, when you try to predict one value, you should provide also 10 columns with the same order. To solve it, you have to reproduce the transformation you did in the X_train to the X.

Comment: I did the same transformation to X and X_train, the only difference is in the amount of rows they have. Because I want to predict on more rows than I have trained on. So they have the same columns, but a different amount of rows.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?